# Searching using RegEx for multiple strings that might include pipe character

Tags: c#, regex

I have used a code that searches for multiple string in a set of files that worked fine until I included the pipe character in one of the search strings. It barfed.

This is what I have been using and not sure how to modify it to accept pipe character as part of the search.

Here "fi" is the FileInfo variable for the current file I am searching and searchStr is an array containing the strings I am searching for.

```
foreach (var line in Extensions.WriteSafeReadAllLines(fi.FullName))    // This method fixes the issue of reading lines when file is open.
{
    // Escape "|" character in search strings
    SearchStr = SearchStr.Select(l => l.Replace("|", @"\|")).ToArray();

    string pattern = string.Join("|", SearchStr);  // <-- what if one of the search strings has '|'
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        string theEntireLine = match.Groups[0].Value;
        // do whatever with the line that contains any of the search strings
    }
}
```

Sample lines from a file being searched:

```
2023-10-31 00:34:31:162|2023-10-31 00:34:31:162,[1.23.4:12870],ABC,XX,102,128001dLV816409130                     RLCAYV0B 1M0                  20231025152123                },

2023-10-31 00:34:58:940|2023-10-31 00:34:58:940,[1.23.4:12870],XX,ABC,60,d128101LZ240126628                                       },

2023-10-31 00:34:59:268|2023-10-31 00:34:59:268,[1.23.4:12870],ABC,X,102,128101dLZ240126628                     RLCAYT2R0W8                   20231028060553                },
```

Search for these strings, as input into a text area, one search string per line

```
00:34:31:162|2023-10-31
128101dLZ240126628
```

SearchStr array now contains:

```
"00:34:31:162\\|2023-10-31"
"128101dLZ240126628"
```

And it matches every line that has "2023-10-31" and even then rather than returning the entire line, it returns "2023-10-31"

If I use RegEx.Escape, as suggested by Nick, "pattern" will look like:

```
\\|00:34:31:162\\|2023-10-31|128101dLZ240126628
```

Comment: The backslash in regex is the escape string. Before doing the string.Join, you could go through each entry in SearchStr and replace "|" with "\|".

Comment: The problem is I am searching multiple strings for which "|" is used in RegEx. If I use RegEx.Escape("|"), won't the pipe character that is part of RegEx be also escaped? I have updated the question with @B.O.B. suggestion, which still doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure why there is "close" vote, this is not a duplicate of any question. I do search extensively before deciding it is time to post and ask experts.

Comment: The basic question is: if I am searching for multiple strings and one or more of the strings happen to have "|" in them, how do I proceed, given RegEx uses "|" as a separator itself? If I search for 1234|5678, rather than returning lines with 1234|5678, it returns lines matching 1234 or 5678. Trying to replace "|" with "\|" or using RegEx.Escape("|") + searchStr did not work.

Comment: You can see in your own SearchStr array that you are somehow double escaping it. You can escape the escape character in regex as well. So if your input is `"00:34:31:162|2023-10-31"`, then your output for escaping it should be `"00:34:31:162\|2023-10-31"`.

Comment: I tried both `l.Replace("|", @"\|")` and `Regex.Escape(l)` in a simple console app, and I get: `00:34:31:162\|2023-10-31|128101dLZ240126628` for output.

Comment: I bet it's the loop. SearchStr exists outside the loop in your example code. That means you are doing `SearchStr = SearchStr.Select(l => l.Replace("|", @"\|")).ToArray();` on each iteration of the loop. You should do the pattern creation outside the loop.

Comment: This is what I mean: https://ideone.com/Gb2NsA, which means this is a duplicate

Comment: @Nick I have no idea what this site is although it seems to be my code sample from here. I did not post there and not sure how this ends up there. A copy/paste of my code sample and it counts as duplicate!? And downvoting both the question and answer?

Comment: @NoBullMan the `ideone` code is code that *I* wrote on that site to demonstrate that using `Regex.Escape` would solve your problem (which is what the duplicate and your accepted answer show). `ideone` is just a sandbox for playing with various languages. As for the downvotes, they were not mine (if you look at my rep for the last day, you'll see it has only changed by a multiple of 5, so no `-1` penalty for a downvote).

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the info. I will use that site for future testing. I thought duplicate meant there is already a similar answered question, asked by someone else, which would indicate I hadn't done my homework, and not that my sample code with someone's response/answer would indicate duplicate. Anyways, thank you all for your input and B.O.B for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, first, move the pattern creation outside the loop or you are going to multi-escape the pattern on each iteration of the loop.

Second, it sounds like you want the entire line for anytime a line matches any of the search string. For that you just  need to reference back to the `line` variable in your for loop:

```
SearchStr = SearchStr.Select(l => Regex.Escape(l)).ToArray();
string pattern = string.Join("|", SearchStr);

foreach (var line in Extensions.WriteSafeReadAllLines(fi.FullName))
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(line, pattern))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"This line matched one or more of the search patterns: {line}");
    }
}
```

Comment: PS, here is 2 lines I get back using your example lines + search filter:
`2023-10-31 00:34:31:162|2023-10-31 00:34:31:162,[1.23.4:12870],ABC,XX,102,128001dLV816409130                     RLCAYV0B 1M0                  20231025152123                }` and `2023-10-31 00:34:59:268|2023-10-31 00:34:59:268,[1.23.4:12870],ABC,X,102,128101dLZ240126628                     RLCAYT2R0W8                   20231028060553                },`